# CSS bubbling up from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, components

Trying to address all h1 elements in a child component but the class styling bubbles up to address all h1 elements in entire DOM. How restrict styling to component to which stylesheet is imported?

````
```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/principlesInAoL.css";

export default class PrinciplesInAoL extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Principles in Areas of Life</h1>;
  }
}
```
````

& Beginning of parent component code:

````
```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AoLDescription from "./aoLDescription";
import MetaPrinciple from "./metaPrinciple";
import "../styles/principles.css";
import PrinciplesInAol from "./principlesInAoL";

export default class Principles extends Component {
  render() {
```
````

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need to use inline styling or use a more specific css selector/ add a class selector to the `h1` tag

Comment: Yes, I see, so importing a component means I import its imports too, including stylesheets?

Comment: yes, by importing a stylesheet, you are just adding it into the bundle and loaded/ applied into the entire HTML. If you wanted to see more on how it works look into the css-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any css you add that defines styles by a tagname will apply to every element in the dom with that tagname, so in your case, adding a class name to the `<h1/>` is probably the best option.

In the `PrinciplesInAoL` component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/principlesInAoL.css";

export default class PrinciplesInAoL extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 className="principlesInAoL-h1">Principles in Areas of Life</h1>;
  }
}
```

and in `principlesInAoL.css`, add a definition for that class:

```
.principlesInAoL-h1{
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ReactJS has no view encapsulation (in contrast to Angular). So in order to make CSS rule much stricter you should use CSS selector with higher specificity.